# Jetty 9 RC2 websocket timeout

Tags: timeout, websocket, jetty

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810306/appointment-scheduling....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The support for Sesssion.setIdleTimeout(long ms) was added recently to support JSR-356 (javax.websocket) work we are currently doing.

However, with 9.0.0.RC2 you can do the following to set idle timeout early, before the Session is created (this is being fixed, hopefully will make it into RC3)

**Server Side option A: WebSocketServlet init-param**

In your `WEB-INF/web.xml` for your websocket servlet, specify the following init-param

```xml
<init-param>
  <param-name>maxIdleTime</param-name>
  <param-value>10000</param-value>
</init-param>
```

**Server Side option B: As policy change on WebSocketFactory**

In your WebSocketServlet.configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) call

```java
@Override
public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory)
{
    factory.getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(10000);
}
```

**Client Side option A: As WebSocketClient setting**

```java
WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
client.getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(10000);
client.start();
```

**Annotated @WebSocket option**

This will work for server or client websockets.

Note: you cannot mix WebSocketListener and @WebSocket annotations together

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketClose;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketConnect;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketError;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketMessage;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;

@WebSocket(maxIdleTime=10000)
public class MySocket
{
    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason)
    {
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session sess)
    {
    }

    @OnWebSocketError
    public void onError(Throwable cause)
    {
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onText(String message)
    {
    }
}
```